# How to Open x509certificate in android app

Tags: android, x509certificate2

I got a certificate from web service and I want to display for user.How can I do it? which control should I use?

Comment: SpongyCastle is your library for that

Comment: yes I use spongyCastle but I don't know how do I do it. I wan to display Issued certificate for user and he can view genral tab,detail tan and certificate path in certificate

Comment: You should consider combining what you can learn from http://stackoverflow.com/a/28295134/2413303 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914521/how-to-extract-cn-from-x509certificate-in-java

Comment: Thank you. I try it but I have a certificate and I can extract field from it. but I want to display certificate for user . It is like open google certificate for user on screen